# Bot copy the message url in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Can bot somehow copy the url of the message he just send? I was trying to do something like that but it didnt work

```
channel1.send("test",{
            embed:embed,
          });
const messageurl = client.message.cache.find(URL)
message.channel.send(`${messageurl}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```js
const msg = await channel1.send("test",{
            embed:embed,
          });
channel1.send(`${msg.url}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the options for sending message in a channel is a string or an object. If you use that wrong method, your bot only sends `test` into the text channel. Replace it with `.send({ <options> })` so you can send multiple items.

Second, embed option for sending a message must be an array if you are using discord.js v13:

```js
channel.send({ embeds: [] });
```

Finally, `<textChannel>.send()` method returns a Promise with message sent. Get the message your bot sent by defining `const msg = await channel1.send({ <options> });`(Await is only available in async function). Now we can access the message's attribute such as **ID**, **url**, **author**… etc. The URL which you want is the `msg.url`.
Here is the final code:

```js
(async () => {
    const msg = await channel1.send({
            content: "test",
            embeds: [ embed ],
          });
    channel1.send(`${msg.url}`);
})();
```

Hope this will help you, comment on this answer if you still have any issue about it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
channel1.send({ content: `${msg.url}`, embeds: [embed] })
```